# CGAffineTransform - Pixelated after use

Tags: swift, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

**Problem:**

When using CGAffineTransform I lose the quality of my UIView and all its subviews.

**Code**

Im currently running the following code to scale and move my UIView.

```
    func animate(show: Bool, navigationController: UINavigationController) {
    let viewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.7

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

        if !show {
            var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
            t = t.scaledBy(x: scale,
                           y: scale)
            t = t.translatedBy(x: viewWidth * 0.6, y: 0)
            navigationController.view.transform = t
        } else {
            navigationController.view.transform = .identity
        }

    }) { (complete) in
        if show {
            let sideMenuView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.viewWithTag(-253)
            sideMenuView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

But when I return to my original state everything is pixelated and low quality.

Ive tried on both handset and simulator.
Ive removed the scale factor and the issue still remains.
Ive also tried setting the values to the original.

example

```
     var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
        t = t.scaledBy(x: 1,
                       y: 1)
        t = t.translatedBy(x: 0, y: 0)
        navigationController.view.transform = t
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to retain the quality when using  CGAffineTransform?

Thanks all

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED**

It was simple really.

setting the rasterizationScale resolved the issue.

```
    func animate(show: Bool, navigationController: UINavigationController) {
    let viewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.7
    navigationController.view.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

        if !show {
            var trans = CGAffineTransform.identity
            trans = trans.scaledBy(x: scale,
                           y: scale)
            trans = trans.translatedBy(x: viewWidth * 0.6, y: 0)
            navigationController.view.transform = trans

        } else {
            navigationController.view.transform = .identity
        }

    }) { (complete) in
        if show {
            let sideMenuView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.viewWithTag(-253)
            sideMenuView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```